# How can i change the one particular dropdown option according to another dropdown option selection?

Tags: php, jquery, html, select

I have two dropdown list parallely, this is first one

```
 <select onchange="selchng1(1,this.id)" id="first1" name="sesion[]" class="tx_bx">
<option select="selected" value="select1">- Select -</option>
<option value="14275">Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)</option>
<option value="14276">Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM)</option>
<option value="14277">Session #3: Tues June 28th - Fri July 8th (9-2:00PM)</option>
<option value="14278">Session #4: Tues July 12th - Fri July 22nd (9-2:00PM)</option>
</select>
```

and second one is,

```
<select onchange="selchng1(1,this.id)" id="first_time1" name="time[]" class="tx_bx"><option select="selected" value="select2">- Select -</option>
<option value="14270">#1 only: 1pm</option>
<option value="14271">#1 only: 1:30pm</option>
<option value="14272">#1 only: 2pm</option>
<option value="14273">#1 only: 2:30pm</option>
<option value="14313">#1 only: 3:30pm</option>
<option value="14314">#1 only: 4pm</option> 
</select>
```

now what i need to do is,

when select from first dropdown first option
 `<option value="14275">Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)</option>`

i need to display first three option from second dropdown.

```
<option value="14270">#1 only: 1pm</option>
<option value="14271">#1 only: 1:30pm</option>
<option value="14272">#1 only: 2pm</option>
```

then for remaining options in first select box,

```
<option value="14275">Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM)</option>
<option value="14276">Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM)</option>
<option value="14277">Session #3: Tues June 28th - Fri July 8th (9-2:00PM)</option>
<option value="14278">Session #4: Tues July 12th - Fri July 22nd (9-2:00PM)</option>
```

i need to display remaining options from second select box,

```
<option value="14273">#1 only: 2:30pm</option>
<option value="14313">#1 only: 3:30pm</option>
<option value="14314">#1 only: 4pm</option>
```

How can i do this?.Please advice me.

Comment: You would have to serve up the second options with AJAX. Process the first options selections, an filter the second set of options based on what is chosen from the first and deliver the second set of options accordingly.

Comment: @ckaufman how can i do this in AJAX?. can i use jquery post method?

Comment: No need for AJAX here, that's way overpowered - you know all possible combinations upfront and can save the roundtrip

Answer (score 0):

```
//This stores the options
var options=[
  ["14270", "#1 only: 1pm"],
  ["14271", "#1 only: 1:30pm"],
  ...
  ["14314","#1 only: 4pm"]
];

//This is the index first1 -> first_time1
var index=[
  [],
  [0,1,2],
  [3,4,5],
  [3,4,5],
  [3,4,5]
];

function update_first_time1(selidx) {
  //Get select box options collection
  var o=document.getElementById('first_time1');
  if (!o) return false;
  if (!o.options) return false;
  o=o.options;

  //Empty options
  while (o.length>0) o[o.length-1]=null;

  //Get the index of options to add
  var a=index[selidx];

  //Add these options
  for (var i=0; i<a.lenght; i++)
    o[o.length]=new Option(options[i][1], options[i][0]);

  //done!
}

//First select box: hook onchange 
<select onchange="selchng1(1,this.id); update_first_time1(this.selectedIndex)" id="first1" name="sesion[]" class="tx_bx">
...
</select>
```

Comment: when i comment the o.remove() line then no javascript error displays, but the functionality not work.

Comment: AHA - bad, bad browser ... is it IE? Whatever, I replaced `o.remove()` and `o.add()` with the older access pattern, please retry